# the proper way to write an initialize function

Tags: javascript

I want to use an initialization function that will be called after a user visits a part of the application, but after that first visit I don't want to initialize anymore. A simple way to do this is using a flag and an if-statement, but there is a nicer solution to this problem:
in other languages I changed the body of the init function so that after the call of this method.

Can this be done in Javascript too? I wrote something like this, but eclipse says that it is an illegal assignment:

```
function initEdit(){
...

this = function() {};
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that `this` refers to the function itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but `this` doesn't refer to the function, so you have to specify it by name:

```
function initEdit(){
  ...

  initEdit = function() {};
}
```

Another alternative, that might be easier to follow, is to just use a variable:

```
var initialised = false;

function initEdit(){
  if (!initialised) {
    initialised = true;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the alternative. The intent is more obvious when the method is simpler.